# How to start a numbered list on the same line as its label or heading

Tags: lists, enumerate

```
Example: 1. Item1
         2. Item2
         3. Item3
```

I am new to latex and trying to achieve something like above in latex (instead of **Example:** there can be any text). I have read answers with the same effect for a bulleted list but did not find any for a numbered list. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your formatting objective is to place the `enumerate` environment inside a `minipage[t]` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for fancy 'enumerate' and 'itemize' environments
\begin{document}

Example:
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth} %  choose a suitable width
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,left=0pt]
\item Item1
\item Item2
\item Item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the  `wide=` key of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Example: 
    \begin{enumerate}[wide=\widthof{Example: \hspace{1.5em}}, label=\arabic*., nosep,%
    before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip},]
        \item Item 1.
        \item Item 2.
        \item Item 3.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will also do what you want. The advantage of this approach is 1) you don't have to specify widths, and 2) it automatically breaks across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[Example:]\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item Item1
\item Item2
\item Item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]